# How does htaccess work when using cPanel and addon domains

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

When you have cPanel hosting and you use addon domains, the domains are "housed" in a folder within the `public_html` folder (by default), for example:

```
A) public_html/.htaccess
B) public_html/addondomain_1/.htaccess
C) public_html/addondomain_2/.htaccess
```

It's my understanding that anything I put in the htaccess file A) applies to everything within it, which should include B) and C).

So, as an example, adding a blocked IP address to A) would also be blocked on B) and C).

But I query this purely because B) and C) are different domains when viewed in the browser. I've tried testing it but without much luck and going through pages of documentation hasn't helped me come to a conclusion.

If I block someones IP in A) will it block them from websites B) and C)?

Answer (score 1):

[Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#how) are pretty clear:

> The configuration directives found in a .htaccess file are applied to the directory in which the .htaccess file is found, and to all subdirectories thereof. However, it is important to also remember that there may have been .htaccess files in directories higher up. Directives are applied in the order that they are found. Therefore, a .htaccess file in a particular directory may override directives found in .htaccess files found higher up in the directory tree. And those, in turn, may have overridden directives found yet higher up, or in the main server configuration file itself.

This is a feature of Apache, not of cPanel. It does not matter if you're running with cPanel or not — Apache is still going to traverse parent directories and apply their `.htaccess` directives.

Comment: So if I block someones ip in A) it will block them from websites B) and C)?

Comment: As long as their document roots are subdirectories of the directory where your `.htaccess` file is located, yes.

Comment: Note, however, that if you are using `mod_rewrite` in the parent directory (which you might be if you are blocking IPs) _and_ you are using mod_rewrite in the addon domain's .htaccess file then you will need to explicitly specify `RewriteOptions Inherit` (in the addon domain) in order to inherit/process the parent directories mod_rewrite directives.